# How do I get a lot of Stunt Driver points?

Tags: just-cause-2

I've been driving around in Just Cause 2 like a maniac at full speed but I very rarely get any stunt driver points. I'll occasionally get one - or, rarely, two - when I drive into a sharp incline that makes my car jump into the air, but it doesn't seem to work consistently. Very often I won't get anything. In 20+ hours of play I've only got around 15 points, so getting the 'Stunt Driver' achievement seems a long way off.

Are there specific types of stunt that are rewarded more? Do certain vehicles make it easier (fast ones, I guess)? Are there prime 'farming' spots?

Comment: The airplane way looks *awesome*. I need to try it. I've amassed about 50 points yet. Go to one of the Strongholds which are located on mountains. The road leading down from these strongholds are usually winding in an S shape, so if you go perpendicular to the S shape you basically get sorta steps. I continuously kept driving like this, and got stunt points. Basically, drive off a hill/mountain which has many ledges. Be careful, though. Sometimes the car overflips and BOOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did this is the way shown in this video:

Essentially, go to the airport and steal the Titus ZJ sports car parked on the pedestal out in front.  Drive at full speed around the circular road that is at the end of the entry road to the airport.  The car is fast enough to earn Stunt Driver points easily, but the circular road's radius is great enough that you shouldn't have problems staying on the road at the car's full speed.

It's a bit tedious, but it's a very fast way of getting this achievement.

Another method I found:

For this one, take the Titus into the airport, and attach it to one of the jets as it takes off.  Get in the car, and the jet will pull you and the car along through the air.  If you hold the accelerator even while the car is in mid-flight, you'll continue to earn Stunt Points.

Going into the airport is likely to raise the ire of the military, though.  Despite the risk, this seems like a more "fun" way to get this achievement.